# UrlRewrite slug SEO Error 500

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(admin|agent|API|API-manager|API-owner|cron|email|engine|landing|manager|media|owner|promo|QR|shop|upload|web)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule p/([0-9]+) http://www.goubaoapp.com/promo.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ([^/]+) http://www.goubaoapp.com/web.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

When i match the last rule i have error 500.
I tested on "htaccess tester web site" but it seems correct. What is wrong?

Thank you

UPDATE:
This is what I want:

```
url/admin -> url/admin
url/QR -> url/QR

url/abc123 -> url/web.php?slug=abc123
url/abc123/ -> url/web.php?slug=abc123
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)$ http://www.goubaoapp.com/web.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @Horizon_Net looks like an answer to me? But I don't know the problem area.